# Git mirror with issues and pull request history

Tags: git, github, transfer, mirror

I just [mirrored a github repo](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/).

Like this:

```
git clone --bare git@github.oldproject/oldproject.git

cd oldproject.git

git push --mirror git@github.com:newproject/newproject.git
```

This works great but closed issues and pull requests are not transfered?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull requests and issues are not part of git. They are features of the GitHub or other tools.

If you wish to checkout pull request locally follow those instructions:
https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/

Comment: Hmm, i have a lot of closed pull requests that I would like to transfer. So that's not possible I guess?

Comment: Why do you need closed pull requests? they should be merged into your branches. In Github you simply see the content of the pull request, the actual changes are i your branches

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at this tool: https://github.com/IQAndreas/github-issues-import

> This Python script allows you to import issues and pull requests from
> one repository to another; works even for private repositories, and if
> the two repositories are not related to each other in any way.

Note: This does only work with password logins (not ssh).