# Migrating from GitHub to Azure GitRepos

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I am currently using GitHub. We recently added Azure CI/CD, and got to know that we can use Azure GitRepos as well instead of GitHub for free.

What all things will be maintained during this transition? e.g. versioning history / pull requests etc.. Or I will loose everything except the code :P

Thanks!

Comment: If Azure is giving you regular Git, then you'll lose nothing.  Git is a distributed system.  There's nothing special about what's on GitHub vs what's on your own workstation.  The same should be true going from Github to another poster.  The only thing you may lose are the Github-specific tools that aren't a standard part of Git, like Github Actions.  I expect there's an equivalent in Azure.

Comment: Oh yeah..pull requests are a local thing.  I forgot about that. I would hope someone would have written a migration tool for that.  Can't be too hard to do.

Comment: There's some good information in this post about pull requests.  What's interesting is that it's more of an idea than a specific tool.  In your case though, and for most of us, we're talking about Github pull requests.  Anyway...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289599/are-pull-requests-part-of-git-or-a-feature-of-tools-like-github-gerrit-and-atl

Comment: Did the answer docs work?

Comment: I did not tried it yet..

Answer (score 2):

Azure Git Repos uses the same technology as Github, so you can keep versioning history, but pull requests won't move, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745614/git-mirror-with-issues-and-pull-request-history). That said you can use `git clone --mirror https://repoUrl` to copy your repository and branches including history.

You can read about [Mirroring a repository in another location](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository-in-another-location).

IMO before you delete anything try to make POC on one repo and see how things work and make a decision on everything else.

More info regarding PR part:

- [! [remote rejected] errors after mirroring a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265266/remote-rejected-errors-after-mirroring-a-git-repository)
- [GitHub clone from pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947789/github-clone-from-pull-request)